# consult register servise using java code localhost port and missing path

Tags: java, consul

I have java code to insert services into my consul sevice, using spring-cloud-starter-consul-all and java code like this:

```
if (response.getValue().isEmpty()) {

    NewService service = new NewService();
    service.setAddress("serverhere.com");
    service.setPort(8200);
    service.setId("servideId");
    service.setName("serviceName");

    client.agentServiceRegister(service);
}
```

I need to add also parameters, or path, like:

```
http://serverhere.com:8080/parameter1/parameter2.
```

I do not know where to insert the parameters: /parameter1/parameter2.

I have tried adding this code:

```
//HealthCheck
    NewService.Check serviceCheck = new NewService.Check();
    serviceCheck.setHttp(service.getHealthCheck());
    serviceCheck.setInterval(healthCheckInterval);
    serviceCheck.setTimeout(healthCheckTimeout);
    
    //Path
    NewService.Check serviceCheckPath = new NewService.Check();
    serviceCheckPath.setScript("/parameter1/parameter2");
    serviceCheckPath.setInterval(healthCheckInterval);
    
    
    List<Check> serviceCheckList = new ArrayList();
    serviceCheckList.add(serviceCheck);
    serviceCheckList.add(serviceCheckPath);
    
    newService.setChecks(serviceCheckList);
    
    client.agentServiceRegister(newService);
```

I get this error:
OperationException(statusCode=400, statusMessage='Bad Request', statusContent='Request decode failed: json: unknown field "Script"')

Could you help me to find the appropiate field to save path related to a service.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consul [service definitions](https://www.consul.io/docs/discovery/services#service-definition) can only contain IP and port information. The catalog does not have a first class method for storing HTTP path information.

You could potentially use the [`Meta`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/agent/service#meta) field of the service registration to store this info in a `path` key. You would then need to write logic in your applications to perform the service discovery using the HTTP API, and concatenate the IP, port, and path from the meta field to form the full URL.